# Cannot convert Crystal Report to PDF "Failed to Export the Report"

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8.1, pdf, crystal-reports

Our users cannot export their Crystal Reports to PDF in Windows 7 and 8/8.1.
An error message pops up saying "Failed to export the report".
Users noticed this occurred after a recent Microsoft update.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft had released an update KB3102429 that included two fonts, Times New Roman and Ariel.  These newly updated fonts were at version 6.88.

(Fonts are located here C:\Windows\Fonts)

You have a choice:

- Uninstall KB3102429, which will revert the fonts back to v6.87
- Keep the update, and replace the fonts with either a newer version v6.90 or an older version v6.87.

Most people in our world are choosing to uninstall the update.

(This is not an issue with Windows 10, because the fonts are at v6.90)